# i want to change the names of the files and this change is in the middle. i basically need to remove a part of the variable and write something else

Tags: bash, loops, file, rename, parameter-expansion

i have tried this

```
$ls 
casts.c endian.c ptr.c signed-unsigned-representations.c signed-unsigned.c test-hard-link.c

$for i in *.c;do mv "$i" "$i"__swa.c; done

$ls
casts.c__swa.c endian.c__swa.c ptr.c__swa.c signed-unsigned-representations.c__swa.c signed-unsigned.c__swa.c test-hard-link.c__swa.c
```

and i know that because my i variable is *.c so when i try to rename and add the (__swa.c) part it just gets added on the variable name.

i need the files to be renamed like this:

```
casts__swa.c  endian__swa.c  ptr__swa.c  signed-unsigned-representations__swa.c                signed-unsigned__swa.c  test-hard-link__swa.c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Bash's [parameter expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal) , you could do something like this:

```sh
for f in *.c; do
    echo mv "$f" "${f%%.c}"__swa.c
done
```

(Remove the `echo` of course, if it looks like it will do what you want)

But I generally rather use the more flexible `rename` using Perl, as suggested in the answer by Cyrus.

Answer (score 1):

With Perl's standalone `rename` or `prename` command:

```
rename -n 's/\./__swa./' *.c
```

If output looks okay, remove `-n`.